# Distinct records ordered by join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

We have `locations` that `has_many` `images` and `images` `belongs_to` a `User`. I want to get all of the distinct locations that the user has taken a photo at ordered by the `created_at` on images. I would like to try and accomplish this as a single query but I haven't been able to find a way where this works.

I have tried variation of `Location.joins(:images).where(images: { creator: user }).order('images.date_uploaded DESC').distinct` but they result in errors such as:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...ype" = $1 AND "images"."creator_id" = $2 ORDER BY images.dat...`

or ununique results.

It looks like if I use `uniq` then it returns the correct results, but I believe that has to load the records from the DB into an array to uniq them.

#### Update 1

I have tried using SQL (which I am no expert in) using the following query:

`SELECT DISTINCT(locations.id), images.date_uploaded, images.id FROM locations
JOIN images on locations.id = images.location_id
WHERE images.creator_type = 'User'
AND images.creator_id = 105
ORDER BY images.date_uploaded, images.id`

But I still get duplicates.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the tables structure. Did you try plain SQL ? Can you add that?

Comment: But if you have two images with the same location, which image's `date_uploaded` do you want to use? That's what the database is complaining about in a round-about way.

Comment: I updated the question @PeS